# TextView setTextIsSelectable(true) crashing application

Tags: android, string, textview, classcastexception, spannable

I wanted to make my data in textview selectable for copy paste. For this,
I am setting textIsSelectable flag to true in my textview as following:

```
textView.setText("Hello"); 
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

I am getting following exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.text.Spannable

**UPDATE **
My xml layout :

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="end" android:bufferType="spannable" android:fontFamily="sans-serif" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: `textView..setTextIsSelectable(true);` remove the extra dot `.` . And post your xml code as well

Comment: My bad. was just a typo while editing the question here. But the issue still remains

Comment: That's why I asked you in plain to also post the xml code!

Answer (score 0):

Add buffertype while setting text

```
textView.setText("Hello", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: did that too.. still getting same exception

Comment: <TextView
                android:id="@+id/voucher_contact_detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:bufferType="spannable"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="@color/flight_terminal_tv_color"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

Comment: nope not working. Although i was able to copy the data but it crashed afterwards. Same exception

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
textView.setText(new SpannableString("HELLO"));
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Comment: app crashed with same exception

Comment: I don't understand why just using android:textIsSelectable="true"  not enough

Comment: read this for spannable text's usage:http://takeoffandroid.com/android-views/android-spannable-text-view-to-change-color-size-style-and-adding-click-event-for-particular-word/

Comment: try remove `android:textIsSelectable="true"` from xml